# Convex hulls in an infinite dimensional simplex

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, simplex

I have the following problem:

Let

$$S=\{x\in R_{+}^\infty \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=1\}$$

be an infinite simplex.

Suppose $\hat{S}$ is a countable subset of $S$ such that

1. for each $x\in \hat{S}$ only at most finitely many coordinates are non-zero, denote the set of those coordinates $N(x)$;
2. for any $x\neq x’$, $x, x’ \in \hat{S}$, $N(x)\cap N(x')=\emptyset$.

Claim: No $x\in \hat{S}$ can be represented as a convex combination of other elements of $\hat{S}$.

I find the result rather obvious, but I do not know how to write the proof formally.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\hat{S}$ is linearly independent. To see this assume:
$$
v = a_1 x_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n = 0
$$
where $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \hat{S}$. Let $\pi_i : S \to \Bbb{R}^\infty$ be the projection onto the span of the $e_i$ with $i \in N(x_i)$, where the $e_i$ are the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^\infty$. Then, by condition 2:
$$
\pi_i(x_j) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{l@\quadl}
      0 & \mbox{if $i \neq j$}\\
      x_j & \mbox{if $ i = j$}
   \end{array}\right.
$$
whence, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, $\pi_i(v) = a_i x_i = 0$ so that $a_i = 0$ (since, by definition of $S$, $x_i \neq 0$).
As $\hat{S}$ is linearly independent, no $x\in \hat{S}$ can be written as a convex combination of other elements.